# How to add hyperlinks strings within gmail in google sheet using

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google form which connected to a google sheet. When filling out the questionnaire, the user will immediately get a mail based on which options the user chose.

Assume that the option:

```
A
B
C
D
```

If the user chose the option A,  will get the content(with hyperlinks):

1. A1(with A1’s hyperlink)
2. A2(with A1’s hyperlink)
3. A3(with A1’s hyperlink)

My problem is that I can’t do this at the same time.
I only can do with only plain text.

[image: Here is my google app script.]

Comment: Try sending the email as [templated html](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set de `Advanced Options` params to the `MailApp.send();`

For example

```
MailApp.send({
  to: currentEmail,
  subject: subjectLine,
  htmlBody: `<p>Clic <a href="${urlLink}" target="_blank">here</a> for details</p>` // This htmlBody param makes an HTML link in Mail Body.
});
```

To see the full list of Advanced Options visit https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#advanced-parameters_1